# I need bash find behaviour explained when using -newermt and -exec ls {}

Tags: bash, find

I have this command:

```
find /var/cache/pkg  -newermt 2020-01-30 | grep 'kdeaccessibility-4.14.3_1'
```

Which returns nothing.  I change it to this:

```
find /var/cache/pkg  -newermt 2020-01-30 -exec ls -D '%F' -l -t -r {} \; | grep 'kdeaccessibility-4.14.3_1'
```

and this is returned:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel        556 2017-07-14 kdeaccessibility-4.14.3_1-6dc124e39c.txz
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel         40 2017-07-21 kdeaccessibility-4.14.3_1.txz -> kdeaccessibility-4.14.3_1-6dc124e39c.txz
```

So, the `-newermt` option seems to be disabled by the `-exec` option.  But I do not understand why.

However, if I add the `-type f` option then the find works as expected.

```
find /var/cache/pkg  -type f -newermt 2020-01-30 -exec ls -D '%F' -l -t -r {} \; | grep 'kdeaccessibility-4.14.3_1'
```

Nothing is returned. I infer from this that presence of a symbolic link is causing the behaviour but I do not understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think the issue is that your `find ... -exec ls ... {} \;` (without `-type f` in the `find` argument list) will run `ls` also for any matching directories, resulting in `ls` listing the entire contents of those directories (unless you add the `-d` option to the `ls` argument list).

Comment: Adding `-d` to the `ls` options and removing `-type f` from `find` did indeed return the expected behaviour.  Thanks.